# C# 403 error because the file contains an inaccessible image? or what?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a stream from a url:http://actueel.nl.pwc.com/site/syndicate.jsp  but i get the 403 error. It doest requier login. I used fiddler to check why IE can open it while my code doesn't. What i got was that there were 2 connections done when opening the link in IE. 1 succeeded while the other got a 403. The 403 was a sublink to a giff image. Seems like the xml is a public file, but the image it contains is located in a inaccesible folder.

I need to know how to ignore the image so i can still get the rest of stream. this is my code to test it(by the way..i tryed with WeClient too and headers) :

```
try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://actueel.nl.pwc.com/site/syndicate.jsp");

    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
catch(Exception ex){
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Thanks for your reactions ;)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dmytro. The WebRequest is *NOT* attempting to download the gif image referenced in the jsp file, only the contents of the jsp itself is being downloaded.  Try looking carefully (in Fiddler) at the IE request compared to yours -  only the url but also all the request/response headers - and see if anything else is missing, such as cookies or ACCEPT headers.

Comment: Yes, there were difference.... i changed the most in my code, but used WebClient..the only thing i dint matchup was the Accept headers. I dint find how to do that with the WebClient

Answer (score 0):

Using Wireshark and wget, the differences were in the headers only.

The remote server requires User Agent and an Accept headers.

eg:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://actueel.nl.pwc.com/site/syndicate.jsp");
((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = "stackoverflow.com/q/4233673/111013";
((HttpWebRequest) request).Accept = "*/*";
```

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to read the StackOverflow FAQ, and mark the best answer as accepted.